# AngularJS - PHP - failed insert data (localStorage) into mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I just store the input data into the Local Storage. 
With $http.post I just get the data and post them to my backend.php

```
$scope.insertdata=function() {
      $scope.stored = localStorage.getItem('todos');

      $http.post("backend.php", {'dataTodos': $scope.stored})
      .success(function(data,status,headers,config) {
        console.log('Success!');
      });
    }
```

Here is my backend.php

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$storedTodos = mysql_real_escape_string($data->dataTodos);

mysql_connect("localhost", "root","");
mysql_select_db("div");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ontodos(`todo`) VALUES('".$storedTodos."')");
```

The browser log (success), nothing else,

but my database is empty. Who is the error?? Hope anyone can help me.

Comment: Why aren't you using `mysql_error` to check whether or not the operation yielded some errors? Also, you probably shouldn't use the deprecated mysql.